# can't define padding and margins in external css sheet

Tags: php, html, css

I'm trying to define some css styling to an < a > element, in particular, padding and margins. I've noticed that when I'm trying to define it in-line, it's working, but when I try to use a class selector in an external style sheet, for some reason it is not working. The weird thing is that other attributes (like height), does work in the external file.

The relevant php code:

```
    <div id='navbar_line'>
    <nav class="home_navbar">
    <div class="container">
        <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse" style='padding:0'>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav home_nav">
                <?php
                // Create the top navigation list by listing the children of the homepage.
                // If the section we are in is the current (identified by $page->rootParent)
                // then note it with <a class='on'> so we can style it differently in our CSS.

                $homepage = $pages->get( "/" );
                $children = $homepage->children;

                $reversed = $children->reverse();

                foreach ($reversed as $child) {
                    echo "<li class='home_navbar_item'>";
                    echo "<a href='{$child->url}'>";
                    echo "<div class='navbar_logo'>";
                    echo    "<img src='{$child->page_logo->url}' alt='{$child->title}' height='30' width='30'>";
                    echo "</div>";

                    echo "</a>";
                    echo "</li>";
                }


                echo "<li class='home_navbar_item'> <a href='{$homepage->url}'>";
                 echo    "<img src='{$meta_data->Logo->url}' alt='{$homepage->title}' height='30' width='30'>";
                 echo "</a>";
                 echo "</li>";
                ?>
            </ul>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
    </div>
    </nav>
</div>
```

The css code:

```
#lower_part span{
  padding:0; 
  margin:0;
  white-space: pre;
}


#navbar_line{
  background-color: #04619c;
  height: 137px;
  margin: auto;
}

#navbar{
  background-color: #04619c;
}

.home_navbar_item a {
  height: 300px;
  padding:0; 
  margin:0;
}

.navbar_logo{
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: white;
  /*border-radius: 50%;*/
}

.carousel_image{
  width:100%;
}

.hebrew_text{
  text-align: right;
}


#scrollable_body{
  height: 100px;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

.scrollable_content{
  padding:0;
  overflow: scroll; overflow-x:hidden;
  height: 500px;
  /*-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;*/
}

span{
  padding:4em 0 0 0;
  display:inline-block;
}

hr {
  border:none;
  border-top:1px dotted #f00;
  color:blue;
  background-color:#fff;
  height:1px;
  width:50%;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried with a JsFiddle and why not share it? Or share your page so we can have a look. Could be a few reasons actually. Like an *override* (try to **inspect your element** in the browser to see what CSS is executed) and try to set the property in `!important` in your external CSS. Otherwise, could be a mistake in the name with the tag (an other reason to inspect it to see it's at least called).

Comment: It might be nice if you told us which element you were having trouble with ?!?!?!? Rather than us having to guess

Comment: you're right. sorry, it's the <a> element. Didn't see that it's being read as html, and got omitted from the text.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you just can't override previous defined padding & margin, while you doing that inline, inline styles have bigger priority and applies.

Try to read this article, it can helps to understand a problem https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity